# sort a varchar field numerically in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the `varchar` field named **_tid**, normally which contains numerical field, but it is also possible that may be contain string field. Now i wanted to to **sort the column by numerically rather than lexicographically**.
Here the query i've used,

```
mysql> select _tid,_name from teacher order by _tid;
```

which returns the following row set.

```
 +------+----------------------+
    | _tid | _name                |
    +------+----------------------+
    | 1    | A.MANIVANNAN         |
    | 10   | M.ELUMALAI           |
    | 100  | SAMPATH.R            |
    | 101  | S.PAULRAJ            |
    | 102  | A.ASHOK KUMAR        |
    | 103  | S.JAYAKUMAR          |
    | 104  | S.CINRAS             |
    | 105  | P.MURUGAN            |
    | 106  | S.VIJAY              |
    | 107  | N.KARTHIKEYAN        |
    | 108  | G.BALAKRISHNAN       |
    | 109  | C.THARANI            |
    | 11   | M.PONNUSAMY          |
    | 110  | J.KANNAN             |
    | 111  | V.MAHENDRAN          |
```

But i want row set like the following,

```
+------+----------------------+
| _tid | _name                |
+------+----------------------+
| 1    | A.MANIVANNAN         |
| 2    | A.PONNIVALAVAN       |
| 3    | B.MUTHU              |
| 6    | R.Kumar              |
| 4    | P.RAJAKALI           |
| 5    | N.Shaunmuga Sundram  |
| 8    | M.Balaji             |
| 7    | V.PALANI             |
| 9    | J.RANJITH            |
| 10   | M.ELUMALAI           |
| 11   | M.PONNUSAMY          |
```

Comment: An idea: pad your values with 0s from the left and sort that.  (Have a look at [`lpad()` function.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad))  Otherwise, it doesn't seem to be a good idea to store data of different types in the same field.

Comment: I upvoted @dezso's comment because of 'it doesn't seem to be a good idea to store data of different types in the same field'. Furthermore, if that field is the primary key and you are using innodb, be aware the length of that primary key will be added to every [secondary index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html) of your table

Answer (score 5):

Two possibilities:
Either pad your values with zeros from the left and sort based on that:

```
SELECT _tid, _name FROM teacher ORDER BY lpad(_tid, 3, '0');
-- choose an appropriate number instead of 3
```

or cast your values to a number (similar to Aaron W's solution, apart from here I cast explicitly, and that is a clearer solution):

```
SELECT _tid,_name FROM teacher ORDER BY cast(_tid as decimal);
```

Be careful if you have non-number strings in your field:

```
SELECT cast('something' as decimal);
0
SELECT 'something' + 0;
0
```

Comment: The second option sorts *better* with characters in the value (see [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ea7b/2)) But it generates the following warnings on anything with a non-numeric character: `Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '1a' `

Answer (score 3):

I've gotten around this before by adding zero to the column

```
select _tid,_name from teacher order by _tid + 0
```

**edit**

This had me thinking a bit more so I decided to run a simple test for speed.  I'm sure the way you choose depends on the values you have in your database and how you want it to sort, but I created the following table and then inserted 100,000 random teacher names. Using a Windows 7 Pro 32-bit, MySQL 5.5.8

```
CREATE TABLE `teacher` (
  `_tid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I ran each query ten times and averaged the query time

```
select _tid,_name from teacher order by _tid + 0;
-- 0.60ms

SELECT _tid, _name FROM teacher ORDER BY lpad(_tid, 5, '0');
-- 0.68ms

SELECT _tid,_name FROM teacher ORDER BY cast(_tid as decimal);
-- 0.63ms
```

I'm sure the results varied because I have a couple VM's running along with only having 250MB - 500MB of available RAM, but it was a quick test to see if there was much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have used  dezso's padding method in the past, but not too long ago I found a simple solution, which was to sort the field first using its length, then its value:

```
SELECT _tid,_name FROM teacher ORDER BY length(_tid), _tid;
```

which causes single digit values to sort before double digit values, and double digit to sort before 3-digit, and so on.  I have not bench-marked the performance however.